# Installing rsvg library in R 4.0.2 (conda-forge)

Tags: r, ubuntu, conda, rsvg

I'm facing difficulties downloading the r package *rsvg*. I created first an environment with conda for the latest R version 4.0.2 following these [instructions](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-base). I was able to download many other R packages & bioconductor packages without problem, however, this one produces huge pile of lines while configuring it and ends with errors downloadind its dependencies (`systemfonts, stringi, stringr, gdtools, magick, svglite, knitr`). My exact command is `install.packages("rsvg", dependencies =T)`. Trying to download each of those packages produced also a tree of required dependencies (with configuration fail at the end of each).

Among the lines I noticed this error `/user/include/freetype2/freetype/config/ftheader.h:3:12: fatal error x86_64-linux-gnu/freetype2/config/fthreader.h no such file or directory` which make me suspect that my R installation is incopmlete or corrupted. I tested it with other R versions (e.g. R [3.6.0](https://anaconda.org/r/r)) yet the same error appear. Installing it on windows (Rstudio 3.6.2) also didn't work, and now I'm wondering if this package needs to be installed differently or it is system related problem? Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: When you install with R's `install.packages` function you have to make sure that you install all non-R dependencies into the conda environment manually. The error you posted hints towards `freetype` not being installed. You would get it via `conda install freetype`.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work, I installed first freetype as you kindly suggested, but I still got the same error (I updated the error). It seems whenever I try to download any R package that relys on fonts this error appears. I also downloaded freetype2 by following [1] and the outcome was: no new packages were installed, i.e. it is there but somehow this ftheader file is pointing to another that doesn't exist. [1] http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/06/install-freetype-2-8-in-ubuntu-16-04-17-04/

Comment: I agree that it looks like a library issue. My experience has been that using most of the standard R routes to install packages (`install.packages`, `BioManager::install`, or `devtools::*_install`) are prone to this problem because they are unaware of how Conda manages the dependencies. Personally, my workflow for Conda-managed R instances is to always use Conda to install R packages, e.g., `conda install -c conda-forge r-rsvg`, which I would note has a dependency on `librsvg`.

Comment: thank you very much, that worked & rsvg is now installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new environment and then you can install R 4.+ in Anaconda. Follow these steps.

```
conda create --name r4-base
```

[image]

After activating `r4-base` run these commands

```
conda install -c conda-forge r-base
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 r-base
```

Finally, you will notice `r-basa` version 4 will be installed.

[image]

Thereafter, you can install any supported packages. But with this only, you won't have the ability to use it in the Jupyter notebook. You need to install `install.packages('IRkernel')` and Jupyter notebook as well if you want to use it. Otherwise you are good to go with R-Studio.

For Jupyter Installation and RKernel.

```
conda install jupyter
```

Then open the R console. Write in R console

```
install.packages('IRkernel')
IRkernel::installspec()
```

Congrats! You can use Notebook for Python and R.

Comment: How can I open the R console for executing `install.packages('IRkernel')` after installing jupyter?

Comment: just type `R` in terminal