# Unable to install rsvg package at Ubuntu 22.04 with librsvg2-dev already installed

Tags: r, conda, pkg-config, librsvg, rsvg

I am getting the following error at an Ubuntu 22.04, when trying to install `rsvg` at Rstudio.

> --------------------------- [ANTICONF] --------------------------------
> Configuration failed to find the librsvg-2.0 library. Try installing:
>
> - deb: librsvg2-dev (Debian,Ubuntu, etc)
> - rpm: librsvg2-devel (Fedora, EPEL)
> - csw: librsvg_dev, sunx11_devel (Solaris)
> - brew: librsvg (OSX)
>
> If librsvg-2.0 is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
> PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a librsvg-2.0.pc file. If pkg-config
> is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via: R CMD
> INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'

This problem is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63195888/installing-rsvg-library-in-r-4-0-2-conda-forge), but involving a different context/error message.

The point is:

1. The library `librsvg2-dev` is already installed and updated;
2. From [here](https://github.com/ropensci/rsvg/issues/14), I understood how to check this '`PKG_CONFIG_PATH`'...

- The `pkg-config --libs librsvg-2.0` returns:

> -lrsvg-2 -lm -lgio-2.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lcairo

Which I do not understand completely but sounds ok, as it does not return 'not fond' as in that post.

- The `which pkg-config` returns

> /usr/bin/pkg-config

I am not able to understand this part of the error message:

> If pkg-config is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via: R CMD

The R+RStudio is running with a conda environment. Maybe it is related to it. How to meet system dependencies when a conda environment is used? I understand the `conda install` x `sudo apt-get` issues, and I should opt for `conda install librsvg2-dev` when I have conda environments, but it returns

> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
> current channels:

I made a search at [anaconda page](https://anaconda.org/search?q=rsvg), and I have already installed at the conda environment:

```
conda install -c conda-forge r-rsvg
conda install -c conda-forge librsvg
```

Still without success in installing `rsvg`...

Perhaps the question is Ubuntu related... but not sure... How can I solve it? How must I proceed to

> set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually

As the message appears incomplete?

Any help is appreciated.